# Conocer programáticamente el estado de las cámaras en Motion / Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

Busco la forma de saber programaticamente el estado de las cámaras cuándo hacen streaming con motion usando una raspberry. ( Usb Webcams )

De manera de con un crontab monitorear cuándo haya errores.

Answer (score 0):

Saca una foto de prueba cada cierto tiempo y lo automatizas con el cron.  Comprueba que la salida de la foto tiene contenido (con que no tenga 0 bytes vale), y comprueba que el demonio del motion está arrancado, con un ps -ef|grep motion |wc -l > 1 valdría.